# Enable fade animation on ng-show but disable animation on hide

Tags: angularjs

So, I want the animation to only apply when ng-show is true. I'm having a hard time trying to disable a "fade out" effect. In jQuery this is simply $.hide and not $.fadeOut. How do I achieve this in Angular?

http://jsfiddle.net/7twjd3an/2/

CSS

```
.fadeIn {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.25s;
  transition:all linear 0.25s;
}

.fadeIn.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
}

.fadeIn.ng-show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add different transitions for `.ng-show` and `.ng-hide`

Adding the following to `.ng-hide` would remove the transition styles when you hide the element while retaining the existing transition styles when you show the element:

```
.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: none 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the one. Thank you. Will accept as answer when timer runs down.